# Find non-matching values across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table similar to this:

```
library(tidyverse)
tribble(~PatientID, ~A1.recipient, ~A2.recipient, ~DonorID, ~A1.donor, ~A2.donor,
  #--|---|---|---|---|---
 101, "1", "3", 201, "3", "1",
 102, "1", "2", 202, "2", "68",
 103, "68", "69", 203, "2", "3",
 104, "1", "2", 204, NA, NA,
 )
```

I would like to use R to find values in the two donor columns that are not in either of the two patient columns. My desired output would look something like this:

| PatientID | A1.recipient | A2.recipient | DonorID | A1.donor | A2.donor | A1.mismatch | A2.mismatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 3 | 201 | 3 | 1 | NA | NA |
| 102 | 1 | 2 | 202 | 2 | 68 | 68 | NA |
| 103 | 68 | 69 | 203 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 104 | 1 | 2 | 204 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

I think I need to use the `across` function, but I'm not sure how to do it. Solutions written in dplyr would be great, as that's what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the logic behind your "mismatch" columns?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check, for each row, whether `A1.donor` and `A2.donor` don't have the same value as `A1.recipient` or `A2.recipient`?

Comment: I want to check, for each row, if any of the values in `A1.donor` or `A2.donor` are not present in either of the values in `A.recipient` or `A2.recipient`.

Comment: Your expected output is likely wrong, I suspect you have exchanged A1 for A2 in the 'mismatch' columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>% 
    mutate(A1.mismatch = case_when(A1.donor == A1.recipient | A1.donor == A2.recipient ~ NA_integer_,
                                            TRUE ~ as.integer(A1.donor))) %>% 
    mutate(A2.mismatch = case_when(A2.donor == A1.recipient | A2.donor == A2.recipient ~ NA_integer_,
                                   TRUE ~ as.integer(A2.donor)))
```

Comment: This is great, and exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We want to extract the 'donor' value in all `case_when` it is not `%in%` the "recipient" values. We can call a function `across` the columns that `ends_with` "donor", then compare the values of each `.x` with each of the columns that `ends_with` "recipient".

Your expected output is likely wrong, I suspect you have exchanged A1 for A2 in the 'mismatch' columns.

This will work with any number of donor or recipient columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>%
        mutate(across(ends_with('donor'), ~case_when(!.x %in% c_across(ends_with('recipient')) ~ .x), .names='{.col}_mismatch'))

# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Rowwise: 
  PatientID A1.recipient A2.recipient DonorID A1.donor A2.donor A1.donor_mismatch A2.donor_mismatch
      <dbl> <chr>        <chr>          <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>             <chr>            
1       101 1            3                201 3        1        NA                NA               
2       102 1            2                202 2        68       NA                68               
3       103 68           69               203 2        3        2                 3                
4       104 1            2                204 NA       NA       NA                NA
```

Comment: I hope I wont let you down, @akrun. :-o. But guessing the expected and comming up with solutions simultaneously is a whole other level of difficulty. I struggle between asking for clarifications that may never come or just answer-and-edit

Comment: A quick one, @akrun. How can I edit the `.names` argument so the names of the columns match the OP´s exactly?

Comment: You may use `.names = '{str_remove(.col, "donor")}_mismatch'`

Comment: I didn't use this solution because I specifically don't want to find mismatches across any number of donor or recipient columns. I have values for donors and recipients at A that I want to find mismatches for, and then values at B, and values at C, etc. So `ends_with` would have complicated things.

Comment: Please see that the code I provided finds mismatches for all the columns that end with the pattern, but `individually`, one at a time, as you need. This code searches for missmatches between A1.donor and all recipient columns, then A2.donor and all recipient columns, exactly like the other answers.
If you have columns with B.donor, C.donor or other columns that end with donor etc and this solution is not ok with your data, than you don´t have an actual reproducible example, please elaborate.

Comment: You can also always change the selection helpers in `across()`. You can name the columns `across(c(A1.donor, A2.donor))`, use other selection helpers `across(matches('[:upper]+\\d+\\.donor')` etc

Comment: Indeed, the code above is elegant and works perfectly with the example table I provided. However, my actual data has many more columns that end in "recipient" or "donor," and most of them do not need to be compared. So when I tried the original code on this, it gave lots of errors as it tried to compare columns that were not meant to be compared.

Comment: I then tried your suggestion of changing the helpers in `across()`.  This code also worked perfectly, even on a test table with new columns: `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(c(A1.donor, A2.donor, B1.donor, B2.donor), ~case_when(!.x %in% c_across(c(A1.recipient, A2.recipient, B1.recipient, B2.recipient)) ~ .x), .names='{.col}_mismatch'))`

Comment: However, when I tried that code on my actual data, RStudio just kept going indefinitely. When I would manually stop the code execution, I get this message: "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level."

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
nm1 <-  sub("donor", "mismatch", names(df1)[endsWith(names(df1), 'donor')])

df1[nm1] <- lapply(df1[endsWith(names(df1), 'donor')], function(x) 
    replace(x, Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[endsWith(names(df1), 'recipient')], 
       function(y) x == y)), NA))
```

-output

```
 df1
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  PatientID A1.recipient A2.recipient DonorID A1.donor A2.donor A1.mismatch A2.mismatch
      <dbl> <chr>        <chr>          <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>       <chr>      
1       101 1            3                201 3        1        <NA>        <NA>       
2       102 1            2                202 2        68       <NA>        68         
3       103 68           69               203 2        3        2           3          
4       104 1            2                204 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>        <NA>
```